# Can't grab my scrollView from javascript using UIAutomation

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, xcode4, ios-ui-automation

I can't seem to create a reference to my scrollView. I'm trying to test the login page of an iOS application.

The xib has a UIView that holds a UIScrollView.

I'm trying to grab the scrollView using this javascript:

```
target = UIATarget.localTarget();
application = target.frontMostApp();
window = application.mainWindow(); 
scrollView = window.scrollViews()[0];
```

Printing the objects (using UIALogger.logPass) yields:

```
[object UIATarget]
[object UIAApplication]
[object UIAWindow]
[object UIAElement]
```

window.elements() yields an array containing exactly one element. I've set the scrollViews' isAccessibilityElement to YES in the viewController's viewDidLoad.

What am I doing wrong here?

**[EDIT]**

application.logElementTree() yields:

```
2) UIAApplication [name:App value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:20}, {width:768, height:1004}}]
3) UIAWindow [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:0}, {width:768, height:1024}}]
4) UIAElement [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:20}, {width:768, height:1004}}]
3) UIAWindow [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:0}, {width:768, height:1024}}]
4) UIAKeyboard [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:760}, {width:768, height:264}}]
```

This doesn't look like what's in my xib. I'm expecting the UIAElement (the root view) to hold a UIAScrollView... Running the app everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to solve this I stumbed upon other questions, one which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685511/why-doesnt-uiscrollview-have-an-accessibility-area-in-the-interface-builder). Using that answer I found out that setting the isAccessibilityElement on the UIScrollView to YES somehow cut off the elementTree.

So answer is: set isAccessibilityElement to NO for the UIScrollView.